# Buildozer android debug issues

Tags: python, android, linux, kivy, buildozer

I try to create apk file via

> ```
> $ buildoser init
> $ buildozer android debug
> ```

while I was trying to build it shows these errors:

p.s. this output after I set log_level = 2 in buildozer.spec

```
# Run '/usr/bin/python -m pip install -q  \'appdirs\' \'colorama>=0.3.3\' \'jinja2\' \'six\' \'enum34; python_version<"3.4"\' \'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"\' \'pep517\' \'pytoml\' \'virtualenv\''
# Cwd None
/usr/bin/python: No module named pip
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pip install -q  'appdirs' 'colorama>=0.3.3' 'jinja2' 'six' 'enum34; python_version<"3.4"' 'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"' 'pep517' 'pytoml' 'virtualenv'
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     CONDA_PYTHON_EXE = '/home/owner/anaconda3/bin/python'
#     GLADE_PIXMAP_PATH = ':'
#     XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR = '/var/lib/lightdm/data/owner'
....

#     CONDA_EXE = '/home/owner/anaconda3/bin/conda'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

> ```
> pip -V
> pip 19.2.3 from /home/owner/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
> ```

Comment: Try installing pip.

Comment: pip was installed

Comment: Apparently not in the python that buildozer is calling. Your paste demonstrates that it's installed in /home/owner/anaconda3/lib/python3.7, which is probably different.

Comment: How can I change the path where buildozer want to search python and pip?

Comment: Try changing your $PATH